# How do you pronounce "f(n) = Θ(g(n))" in English?

Tags: pronunciation, mathematics, computing

In [Algorithm's Performance](http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Algorithms/MyAlgorithms/intro.htm), if `f(n) = Θ(g(n))`, then we can say:

> g(n) an asymptotically tight bound for f(n)

How do you pronounce `f(n) = Θ(g(n))` in English? Would it be correct to say "`f(n) is the Theta of g(n)`"?

*bonus question: is there a different pronunciation depending on the location? e.g. US vs UK?*

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Questions about specialized terminology and notation are best handled by subject matter experts. You are likely to receive more and better answers by asking on one of the appropriate mathematics-related Stacks. See e.g. *[Resources for reading mathematics out loud in different languages](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/7978/resources-for-reading-mathematics-out-loud-in-different-languages)* at [MathEducators.SE].

Comment: Thanks. Copied it to [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2860738/how-do-you-pronounce-fn-%CE%98gn-in-english)

Comment: It's "f of n equals theta of g of n" ("eff of en equals theta of gee of enn"). You will get variations in the pronunciation of theta (theeta v. thayta), although not necessarily aligned with US and UK differences.

Comment: That's correct. _f of n equals theta of g of n_ - /'ɛfəvɛn 'ikwəlz 'θetəʔəv 'ʤiyəvɛn/

Comment: I agree with the preceding two comments except it should very likely be "big Theta". Compare [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376740/what-exactly-does-big-%D3%A8-notation-represent)

Comment: @Cascabel I should have deleted this earlier, but now it has its own life, different than its twin!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a programmer/theorist, I typically pronounce asymptotic notation like this:

> *f* of *n* {is, is in, equals} big theta of *g* of *n* (resp. big O, little O, big omega, &c.)

Or in a sort of point-free phrasing:

> *f* {is, is in, equals} big theta of *g*

Although it’s more common to refer to a specific *g*, like these:

> *f* is Θ(log n) (“big theta of log *n*”) in the length of the input.
>
> *f* runs in logarithmic time with respect to the length of the input.

However, the latter usually refers implicitly to big-O (upper bound), not big theta (tight bound / upper and lower bound) unless disambiguated by some other context.

Comment: wouldn't _uppercase_ be better than _big?_

Comment: @Toothrot: In this context, “big” is much more common—computer science courses introduce asymptotics for algorithmic analysis as “big O notation”. It’s also common in mathematics to disambiguate two variables that differ only by case (e.g. *A* vs. *a*) as “big” and “little” rather than “uppercase” and “lowercase”—I don’t know why, maybe just because of brevity.